# List of HLists to HList of Lists?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Basically I want to transpose my object. Is there a simple way to do this? If my HList is large and I don't want to fold.

This is in service of unzipping a List of a high-arity tuples.

Comment: What's wrong with folding over the List? You could start with a HList with empty lists of the relevant type at each element and gradually add elements to it.

Comment: Nothing wrong, was just wondering if there was an interesting transposy function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an existing solution, but it seemed to be an interesting task, so I tried my hand at it.

Assuming we have a list of HLists, like

```
val myList: List[Int :: String :: Boolean :: HNil] = List(
  1 :: "sample1" :: true :: HNil,
  2 :: "sample2" :: false :: HNil,
  3 :: "sample3" :: true :: HNil
)
```

and we want a HList of Lists, like

```
val expected: List[Int] :: List[String] :: List[Boolean] :: HNil = 
  List(3, 2, 1) :: 
  List("sample3", "sample2", "sample") :: 
  List(true, false, true) ::
  HNil
```

we need to create one typeclass. I named it `EmptyOf`. It has a single method that creates an HList containing empty lists.

```
trait EmptyOf[T <: HList, AsList <: HList] {
  def empty: AsList
}
```

Here is the implementation for HNil:

```
implicit val emptyOfHNil: EmptyOf[HNil, HNil] = () => HNil
```

And now for HCons:

```
implicit def emptyOfHCons[H, T <: HList, TEmpty <: HList](
  implicit ev: EmptyOf[T, TEmpty]
): EmptyOf[H :: T, List[H] :: TEmpty] = () => List.empty[H] :: ev.empty()
```

So, for `EmptyOf[T :: U :: HNil, List[T] :: List[U] :: HNil]` our instance's `empty` will return `Nil :: Nil :: HNil`.

With these, we can implement `transpose` by folding on the list of HLists and using a `Poly2` to merge the HLists.

```
object concat extends Poly2 {
  implicit def prepend[S] = at[List[S], S]((list, s) => s :: list)
}

def transpose[T <: HList, U <: HList](lists: List[T])
                                     (implicit emptyOf: EmptyOf[T, U],
                                      zip: ZipWith.Aux[U, T, concat.type, U]): U =
  lists.foldLeft(emptyOf.empty())(_.zipWith(_)(concat))
```

Now `transpose(myList)` should be equal to `expected` (and of the correct type).